# Deleting open file opened by a stream

Tags: c#, .net

In the following Dispose function, we do not dispose our stream instance if we were called from the finalizer.
(yes, I know that this is a somewhat convoluted version of Dispose and it should be protected virtual, but this is the way it's written in the the source I'm referencing, see Essential C# 5.0 link below)

```
class Foo
{
    FileInfo File;
    Stream Stream;

    // yada yada yada more code goes here...    

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Stream != null)
            {
                Stream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        if (File != null)
        {
            File.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, this is due to unpredictable order of GC release of objects, including instance members.

But, the above code will definitely raise an exception (I tested it) if:

1. The client developer forgot to invoke Dispose() directly
2. The finalizer invoked Dispose(false)
3. The stream wasn't disposed yet

So File.Delete() will fail and throw a System.IO.IOException exception.

So my question is,
**what is the proper way of ensuring that both the stream gets closed and the file gets deleted? (even on the event that the developer forgot to manually dispose the object)**
Obviously accessing Stream member (while disposing==false) is unsafe, so there's gotta be a way.

Please note that **FileOptions.DeleteOnClose is not an option**. Here's the motivation: I have a similar class that Open's and Close's some file, and uses the file (i.e. reads data) across method boundaries, and I don't wish to delete the file before the actual end of usage.

Reference
[Essential C# 5.0](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=AEukNeg0eWgC&lpg=PT542&ots=j0jcrjDSdp&dq=c#%20stream%20finalizer&pg=PT539#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Thanks,
Ofir

Comment: You can always implement Finalizer, that will be called by GC in case when Dispose won't be called by Dev

Comment: Note that outside of if (disposing) you should not access other managed objects like FileInfo  since there is no guarantee the have not already been disposes.

Comment: OK, here is an idea, create a stream class yourself, forward all the function calls to an inner stream and delete the file when your stream class is finalized.

Comment: @Bodgan, This is how it's implemented in the book: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=AEukNeg0eWgC&lpg=PT765&vq=FileInfo&dq=c&pg=PT539#v=onepage&q=TemporaryFileStream&f=false I guess you're right though

Comment: @Bodgan, maybe because the FileInfo is not a finalizable type, it is implicitly OK to access it even during finalization? MS defines finalizable as types that override Finalize, FileInfo doesn't qualify as such).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just implement a *recommended* (by Microsoft) *pattern*?

```
// When implementing Dispose, mark it my implementing 
// IDisposable interface. It make you code more readable,
// allow to put using(...) {...}  etc.
class Foo: IDisposable {
  FileInfo File; // <- class, not struct
  Stream Stream; // <- class, not struct

  ...

  // Just useful thing, esp. while debugging
  public Boolean IsDisposed {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  // Since Foo is not a sealed class be ready that
  // it could be inherited: "protected virtual"
  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    // .Net often let you call Dispose many time, inc. on disposed instances; 
    // The same should do we
    if (IsDisposed)
      return;

    // You can access classes (not structs) in "if (disposing) {...}" only
    if (disposing) {
      if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Stream))
        Stream.Dispose();

      if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, File))    
        File.Delete(); 
    }

    IsDisposed = true;
  }

  // MS recommendation
  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(false);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  // No finalizer here: finalizer just make you potential error
  // (resourse leak or Access Violation) unstable and so harder
  // to detect and correct.
}
```

Whenever developer want to use the class, he/she puts simply

```
using (var foo = new Foo(...)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the response. I will use MS recommendation, but my class is responsible for creating the file, and I want it to be responsible for cleaning them up too. The clients of the class use Open(), ReadAt(int pos) and Close() to access the file, but they might forget to call Close() and so I want the class to ensure the stream is properly disposed before attempting to delete the file. I want to ensure that via Finalizer...

Comment: @Ofir Deri: if you implement IDisposable you say "The intsances should be disposed", and this request can be checked in compile time, e.g. by Code Analysis. Usualy we put any IDisposable into using(...) {...} in that case it's .Net to call Dispose() method

Comment: I'm aware of the effect of the 'using' statement, although in my case it is not eligible, since my client developers are accessing the object across method-boundaries. It looks like I must put the responsibility in the hands of the developers to REMEMBER to close the stream (i.e call Close()), as there seems no other way to both ensure proper stream disposal and file removal from disk.

Comment: If some class owns the Foo instance (and passes it across its methods) this class should implement IDisposable as well (Foo itself is a good example: it owns Stream that is IDisposable). "public class Bar: IDisposable { Foo foo; ..."

Comment: Well, it doesn't own it, it is rather just a client of the class.